# String indices must be integer - they are

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, substring, typeerror

I have some code that generates some a start and end position using string.find.

I then substring the string using the string positions.

The code fails with indices must be integers.

Just to make sure they are integers, I have cast them.

Here's the code snippet with a print to show the values:

```
 print("s={0}  e={1}".format(s, e))
 grab=source[int(s), int(e)]
```

and here's the output:

```
s=7478  e=7690
Exception "unhandled TypeError"
string indices must be integers
```

I'm obviously missing something but I have no idea what.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: just for completeness' sake, can you see what doing `type(s)` and `type(e)` returns right after the first line?

Comment: It's ok, I was still in c# in my head. I needed to use : and not comma between the the parameters. as per first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used a `Tuple[int, int]` as the index instead of an `int`.  You probably meant to use the slice notation, which uses a `:` instead of a `,`:

```
source[int(s):int(e)]
```